# eXide document not found

Tags: exist-db

I managed install exist-DB on Mac OS 11.6 and it starts up I can access from http://localhost:8080/exist/

however when I click on eXide, it throws the following error
[image]

Comment: Which version of eXist? You might reinstall eXide via eXist's Dashboard > Package Manager.

Comment: I cannot  seem to find package manager? when accessing by http://localhost:8080/exist there's only the option to access eXide, eXist documentation, monex (which also throws up error) or x-query function documentation

Comment: Again, which version of eXist? Assuming it's the current stable version of eXist (5.3.0), to access Package Manager, go to http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/dashboard, log in as the admin user via the "Login" link, and Package Manager will appear in the left sidebar.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments !

I finally managed to get it working. Maybe it's my Mac but the .jar installer doesn't work so I uninstalled everything including the exist.org in the library sub-folder which I'd missed out on earlier and was probably throwing up the same error.

Re-downloading .img file seems to work now;

```
The steps I did were:
.jar installer only installs folder but no application exists
1.uninstall everything (including subfolder in /library/)
2. download .img file not .jar 
3. re-install and it should work
```